# converting list of one type to another in java

Tags: java, list

I have a list of type File which I need to convert to another type. But it is giving an error `Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.stream.Stream java.util.List.stream()' on a null object reference`.

I have this non empty list "files" which I want to convert

```
List<File> files = FileUtils.listFilesInDirWithFilter(directory,fileFilter,true);

List<MyClass> customer = files.stream()
                            .filter(MyClass.class::isInstance)
                            .map(MyClass.class::cast)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is there any way that I can change it to my required type?

Comment: What is the problem? can you check if files object is 'actually' not null?

Comment: yes I have checked "files". it is not null.

Comment: Is `FileUtils` a class that you wrote?

Comment: No, it is not a class I wrote.

Comment: @Abra. FileUtils is a class in Apache Commons.

Comment: @KnockingHeads please show me method `listFilesInDirWithFilter` in class [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) (because I couldn't find it and that's why I asked the OP)

Comment: You dont need to use MyClass.class at places where you use method references. Try using MyClass only.

Comment: @Abra. Oh yes. Sorry I missed that. You are right. I have been suspecting the same all through as well. The files object is a null reference.

Comment: _No, it is not a class I wrote_ Oh, progress. So can you tell me what library it is in? Or what package it is in?

Comment: @KnockingHeads could you please explain this `Try using MyClass only`  with some code that would be very helpful.

Comment: Yes. 
File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\ashish\\Desktop\\Hello");
        List<File> files = Arrays.asList(Objects.requireNonNull(dir.listFiles()));
        List<String> fileNames = files.stream()
                .map(File::getName)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(fileNames);

Comment: Can you try to add a sysout of files just to make sure it is not indeed `null`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this one:

```
files.stream()
        .map(aClass -> instantiateClass(aClass, "message"))
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new CustomException("blabla"));
```

Method `instantiateClass`:

```
private MyClass instantiateClass(final Class<?> aClass, final String message) {
    MyClass returnedClass= null;
    try {
      returnedClass = (MyClass) aClass
          .getDeclaredConstructor(String.class) // should contain the same parameters count and types like your constructor in MyClass
          .newInstance(message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("The declared constructor for class {} was not found", aClass.getName());
    }
    return returnedClass;
}
```